# The 3D on youtube dosen't work

Tags: youtube, 3d, smart-tv

I just buy a samsung smart tv with the 3D feature. I also have a DVD that plays 3D movies. It works. But when I am going on Youtube and watch a 3D video, it dosen't work. I get a screen splitted in 2 (left and right side). The 3d mode is well active.

Do you have any idea how to do ?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are in the wrong 3D mode on YouTube, try clicking on the settings cog and "options" next to the 3D option.

I'm not sure what mode you actually need for a 3D TV, I'm guessing it is probably Interleaved, from what you describe you are probably in Side by Side mode now.